# WPF: Raising MouseEnter does not change IsMouseOver property

Tags: wpf, mouseenter, ismouseover

So here is the setup.
I call

```
m_CurrentDirectionBtn.RaiseEvent(new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0) 
    { RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseEnterEvent});
```

on a Button (m_CurrentDirectionBtn) while another element (also a Button) has the MouseCapture.

What I would like m_CurrentDirectionBtn to do is behave in the same way as it would when the MouseCapture is not on and the mouse pointer is over it.
In particular I want it to trigger the same style:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource MainHoverEffect}" />
</Trigger>
```

It does not do that and IsMouseOver stays false. 
Before you suggest using

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
```

instead of

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
```

I want to say that while this may be a viable workaround for some, it is not a solution for me and so it will not do as an answer to my question. 
Obviously things like directly setting properties of the m_CurrentDirectionBtn instead of letting the style take effect will also not do as an answer.

What I want to know is 
1. Why is IsMouseOver not getting set? (I did check - it is not) once the MouseEnter is trigggered
and 
2. How to set it? (it's a readonly property).

To expand on #2, I don't want to set IsMouseOver using some glitch like going through private methods of a Button via Reflection (I found a way to do that for IsPressed for example like so):

```
typeof(Button).GetMethod("set_IsPressed", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Invoke(m_CurrentDirectionBtn, new object[] { true });
```

That`s not it either. What I am looking for is a clean way to programatically produce the same effect as if the mouse was actually over the m_CurrentDirectionBtn but without having to know in advance what styles it has and without the styles it could potentially have being restricted in any way.